# login_user issue when Sign Up on Django

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, web

I wrote some code for Register step, i made all the verification on my code in models.py, forms.py, views.py but when i try to signup i have an error i can't register the data in my database(postgresql)/

And i verified, there is non "login_user" in my code

my app is called **login**.

So this is my /login/models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin
# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     otp = models.IntegerField(null=True)
     phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[+][3][3][6-7][0-9]{8}$',
          message="Le numéro de téléphone doit être au format: +33xxxxxxxxx\
               '0622920182 devient +33622920182'")
     phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=12)
     is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)


     def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is the error i have : 
**ERREUR:  la relation « login_user » n'existe pas
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "login_user" WHERE "login_user"."user...**

Comment: @Whodini no, that's not what it's saying. It's saying that the *table* does not exist in the database.\

Comment: @HugoPaull you do not seem to have created the database table for your custom user model. You need to ensure that "login" is in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, and that you have run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: I rename the app as "users" and added this name in INSTALLED_APPS. I made "makemigrations" and i have always the same error but actually it is the relation "users_user"  that does not exist. I tried to make  "python manage.py migrate" and this did not work...the error is **django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - ah you're right. My mistake.

Comment: I deleted all my database that was empty(i'm at the beginning of the project). Makemigrations and migrate commands worked. When i make "python manage.py dbshell", i have configured my manager.py file, the paths are ok but i have this error: **django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting TEMPLATES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.**.

Comment: What does your manage.py file look like?

Comment: I figured out why i had this problem. I modified DIRS of TEMPLATES in settings.py by adding the path to the templates in my users app(users/templates). I made "python manage.py shell" and it worked.